# Fetch records in range of DATE or DATE AND TIME from unix timestamp field

Tags: sql, mysql

I am saving date and time in unix timestamp in mysql database. I want to fetch records in particular range of DATE only (Example 1) or DATE AND TIME both (Example 2).

Example 1:
Fetch records from date = 20/10/2010 to = 22/10/2010

Example 2:
Fetch records from date = 20/10/2010 to = 22/10/2010, from time = 13:20:00 to = 01:10:00

What is the query for this?

Thanks alot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FROM_UNIXTIME function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert a Unix timestamp into a DATETIME data type:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column) BETWEEN '2010-10-20' 
                                     AND '2010-10-22'
```

The BETWEEN operator is inclusive, and you need to use a standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD) for MySQL to implicitly convert a string into a DATETIME, or you'll have to use STR_TO_DATE to convert a string into a DATETIME.  If the time portion is not included in the string, it will default to midnight.  Meaning '2010-10-20' == '2010-10-20 00:00:00'.

Your second requirement isn't clear about when the times are applied.  If 13:20 as of the start date, and 01:10 as of the end - use:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column) BETWEEN '2010-10-20 13:20:00' 
                                     AND '2010-10-22 01:10:00'
```

Last, using the FROM_UNIXTIME function on a column will render an index on the column useless.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for replying. I still have one more case. I want to fetch records based on TIME only. Example: date = anything, from time = 01:15:00 to = 01:15:59. I tried WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column) BETWEEN '2010-01-01 01:15:00' AND '2010-10-26 01:15:59' But i m not getting output

Comment: @user427969: Have you confirmed you actually have data for that time period?  Because it doesn't sound like you do.

Comment: I have these 3 records with query = "FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column)" => 1) 2010-10-20 01:15:08
2) 2010-10-20 01:15:28
3) 2010-10-20 01:15:48

Comment: I got it. I have to use time(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column)) BETWEEN '01:15:00' AND '01:15:59'

Answer (score 0):

To fetch records based on TIME only:

```
WHERE TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column)) BETWEEN '01:15:00' 
                                           AND '01:15:59'
```

Regards